# NullPointerException в javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Объявляю Label

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это поле служит для вывода информации об ошибках, ниже объявлен статический метод, который вызывается из разных уголков программы, а в качестве параметра передается текст ошибки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке ручного тестирование выдает это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал:

1. Выделять память под объект
2. Ставить аннотацию @FXML перед методов SetExportInfo()

Прикольно, что в прошлой программе почти такая же фишка работала, а здесь не работает.

Comment: ну так переменная у тебя никак не проинициализированна, где она  тебя создается вообще? на каком этапе?

Comment: Переменная должна быть не статичной, что бы ее инициализировал FX фреймворк